# React + Node js app hosted on vercel returns 404

Tags: reactjs, express, vercel

I created a netflix clone and i'm trying to launch it. But it returns an error 404 when launching i deployed it to production and tried launching it still gives out the same error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP3eL.png)

This is what the source looks like.
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SaK4.png)

Vercel.json

```
  {
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./server/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
  
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build"  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "vercel": "^28.2.2"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const path = require("path");
const __dirname1 = path.resolve();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname1, "/client/build")));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname1, "/client/build/index.html"), (err) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
  });
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
  })
);
app.use("/api/profile", require("./routes/Profiles"));
app.use("/api/movies", require("./routes/Movies.js"));
app.use("/api/login", require("./routes/LoginRoutes.js"));
```

Comment: Screenshots of code are unacceptable. Please as code as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I actually found a fix. I didn't add the correct path in my vercel.json file.

This is how it was.

```
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"   //wrong path to my server file.
    }
  ]
```

This is what fixed it.

```
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/server/index.js"   //path to my server file.
    }
  ]
```